# Which openssl keypair gen command produces a password-less private key that I can read in Java 17?

Tags: java, kotlin, openssl, rsa, private-key

Burned better part of a day on this.  Google says use PKCS#8 format for the private key, so I issued command (alpine openssl 1.1.1o)

```
$ openssl genpkey -out my.prv.key -algorithm RSA -pkeyopt rsa_keygen_bits:2048
# from https://www.feistyduck.com/library/openssl-cookbook/online/ch-openssl.html
```

When I try to read this with Kotlin code

```
    val stringKey = Files.readString(Path.of("/Users/matthewadams/my.prv.key"))
    val keyFactory = KeyFactory.getInstance("RSA")
    val privateKeySpec = PKCS8EncodedKeySpec(stringKey.toByteArray())
    val key = keyFactory.generatePrivate(privateKeySpec)
```

I *always* get an exception

```
Caused by: java.security.InvalidKeyException: invalid key format
    at java.base/sun.security.pkcs.PKCS8Key.decode(PKCS8Key.java:103)
    at java.base/sun.security.pkcs.PKCS8Key.<init>(PKCS8Key.java:95)
    at java.base/sun.security.rsa.RSAPrivateCrtKeyImpl.<init>(RSAPrivateCrtKeyImpl.java:153)
    at java.base/sun.security.rsa.RSAPrivateCrtKeyImpl.newKey(RSAPrivateCrtKeyImpl.java:90)
    at java.base/sun.security.rsa.RSAKeyFactory.generatePrivate(RSAKeyFactory.java:352)
    at java.base/sun.security.rsa.RSAKeyFactory.engineGeneratePrivate(RSAKeyFactory.java:249)
    ... 121 more
```

How do I generate a password-less RSA private key using `openssl` (on macos w/LibreSSL or alpine w/openssl) that can be read using vanilla Kotlin code running Java 17?

No matter what variation on this I try, nothing works.  Googled a ton to no avail.  I feel like I'm missing something simple.  Even tried stripping off `-----BEGIN PRIVATE KEY-----` & `-----END PRIVATE KEY-----` -- *nothing* seems to work...

Comment: You're attacking the wrong problem. What you need to do is provide the password when generating the private key from what you read from the file. The API supports that. You don't want password-less private keys. Otherwise they are not private.

Comment: @PresidentJamesK.Polk: no, `genpkey` _does_ produce PKCS8 _and_ unencrypted but in PEM, while basic Java (without BouncyCastle added) only supports DER/binary.  (OTOH `genrsa` produces 'legacy' PKCS1.) OP: you need to remove the BEGIN/END lines _and_ decode the remaining base64 to binary ignoring the linebreaks -- j8+ `java.util.Base64.getMimeDecoder()` is a good way.

Comment: @dave_thompson_085 Thanks!  Turns out it was the base64 decoder.  When I used Base64.getMimeDecoder(), everything worked.  I'll write up an answer & tag you, unless you want credit for it.  Let me know.